# Getting to PHP index page on Heroku

Tags: php, heroku, procfile

I created a `Procfile` and `composer.json` file. I have the procfile pointing to the correct directory. For example it will show the contents of `test.html` but not `test.php`.

Here is what I have in my procfile: `web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 /web/`. I am not using an `htaccess` file yet.

When I push a change to Heroku everything in terminal completes correctly. I'm using papertrail for logging and logging info shows that it is finding the document root folder.

After it starts up here is an example of the message it produces:

```
Jan 12 15:03:25 myfabricapp heroku/router:  at=info method=GET path="/test.php" 
host=myfabricapp.herokuapp.com request_id=2c67069c-7f3d-4c35-b0ee-7e33c5f4c041
fwd="24.247.92.152" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=384
```

I'm running this app fine on the MAMP stack. As far as I know I never added any PHP extensions. What might I be missing here?

I have also gotten 403 errors, "You don't have permission to access..."

Thx in advance.

Comment: Show us how you define the `Procfile` ?

Comment: Yes, please include relevant info in questions, we can't guess everything :) The `Procfile`, and any `.htaccess`.

Comment: I edited the original question with that info.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the php file to run. The issue might have been from the version of git I had installed. I updated it and it started working. At the same time, however git didn't update fully. Anyway I have everything updated and running git 2.2. I am trying to deploy a larger php app but mostly hitting dead ends.